# Post Word Document using Wordpress Rest API

Tags: wordpress, rest

I'm using the Wordpress Rest API to upload a post but I don't understand the format of the body parameter. It seems to accept HTML but I'd like it to accept .docx format.  Is that possible?

Comment: The wordpress API _probably_ will not be able to conver a word document to HTML on the fly unless they specifically mention they support it .

Answer (score 0):

> ... I'd like [the WordPress REST API] to accept .docx format. Is that possible?

No, not with the standard API.

You or somebody, could create a plugin to do this conversion as part of the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

Found out I can use the pandoc package to covert .docx to .HTML.

Thanks.